# Webpage display not updated when viewed by external user

Tags: html, browser

For some reason my homepage is displaying older content to certain users. So much so that content from many months ago is displaying in their browser even though the html content is currently completely different. I suggested a clearing of the cache but the problem persists. Has anyone come across this problem before and what solutions were used to solve this?

Comment: Sounds like a caching problem. If it goes away when the user hard-refreshes (usually `Ctrl+Shift+R`), or empties the browser cache, then it's a caching problem.

Comment: I will try the hard refresh approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Wordpess?

If so you may have installed a plug-in at some point called Hyper Cache or something similar, turn it off and then tell them to refresh the page,

Aside from that It could be a DNS issue with crap hosters (happened to me only the other day)
Can you give us a URL etc to check out?

Comment: This is what I see: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17927147/StackOverflow/Screen%20shot%202011-02-06%20at%2023.05.47.png Is this the new page?

Comment: Then all it is, is a user caching issue, tell them to erase browsers cache and/or use CCleaner to sort it all for them :)